# Is there another way to write the possessive -s?

Tags: possessives, contractions

I have a question regarding the possessive. Which one of the two is correct?

1. *Caroline's car*
2. *Caroline her car*

Or are they both correct?

Comment: In what sense is #2 considered a possessive? Are you referring to appositives?

Comment: Perhaps you will get better answers at https://ell.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: #1 is correct. #2 sounds not quite wrong to me, but rather odd. Like the literal translation of very colloquial German: _Karoline ihr Auto_. Not sure that works in English.

Comment: I've come across this form in Elizabethan music titles {eg [My Lord Chamberlain, His Galliard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Lord_Chamberlain,_His_Galliard)}, but I'm pretty sure it's obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

*Caroline her car* is not idiomatic in the everyday English prose of today. It was idiomatic, to some extent, hundreds of years ago. Today, some folks might say or write it to be quaint or poetic. As a learner, you shoud stick with #1 until you reach the advanced level, and even then you may have no need of #2 unless you have need to write in an outdated style.

Comment: Can you cite a source for "Caroline her car" being "idiomatic, to some extent, hundreds of years ago"? I've only ever seen the "Max **his** car" construction used, with **his**: I don't think it's safe to assume that **her** must have been used the same way. Related: [Odd possessive form of a proper name: Why does Dryden write “Lord Nonsuch his” instead of “Lord Nonsuch’s” but “Bibber’s” instead of “Bibber his”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/212654), [Found in Mary'r Room](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/452881)